# ci hmvc query returns empty result set in model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I recently tried to implement wiredesignz hmvc modular extension for Code igniter 2.2.1 found at https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/ 
I followed the instructions in the overview given to install the extension.

My database dump is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('super','sub') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `admin`  
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`, `email`, `passwd`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'deb.pratyush@gmail.com', 'd84c095fc9614ddd8d6cad216956ba11', 'super');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cms`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nav` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'user id',
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `addr1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `addr2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` date NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I am using a model for authentication in the admin module 
  application/modules/admin/models/admin_model.php having
class name Admin_model. code for it is

```
class Admin_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function auth_admin($email, $passwd)
    {
        echo $email.' '.$passwd;
        $sql ="SELECT `id`, `email`, `type` FROM admin WHERE email='$email' AND passwd = MD5('$passwd')";
        $res=$this->db->query($sql);
        echo " res=<pre>".print_r($res, 1)."</pre>";
    }
}
```

Admin controller is at application/modules/admin/controllers/admin.php having class name Admin. code is below:

```
class Admin extends MX_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cms/cms_model');
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin_header');
        $this->load->view('admin_login');
        $this->load->view('admin_footer');
        if(!empty($this->input->post('admin_login')))
        {
            $email = $this->input->post('log');
            $passwd = $this->input->post('pwd');



            $auth_res = $this->admin_model->auth_admin($email, $passwd);
            //print_r($auth_res);
            if(!empty($auth_res))
            {

            }
         }
     }
   }
```

Note that database library is autoloaded in application/config/autoload.php. Same for the url helper.

The output i am getting is below:

```
deb.pratyush@gmail.com pratyush res=

CI_DB_mysql_result Object
(
    [conn_id] => Resource id #38
    [result_id] => Resource id #47
    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 1
    [row_data] => 
)
```

So, the debugging gives an empty result set despite the fact that user input sent through the login form is deb.pratyush@gmail.com as the email and pratyush as password (password is MD5 hashed in users table).

I have even tried hardcoding the values 'deb.pratyush@gmail.com' and 'pratyush' as email and password columns respectively but no luck.

I have been stuck for a lot of time with this. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using codeignator the use codeignator standered of query

Read Manual [CI QUERY](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
 $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('passwd', md5($passwd));
        $query = $this->db->get('admin');
        if (!$this->db->_error_message()) {
            if ($query->num_rows() > 1) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                   print_r($row);
                }
            } else {
               echo "error";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your auth_admin function in the model, I believe you should return the query result to have it accessed in your controller. Right now your $auth_res variable in your controller is empty as there is nothing returned from the function in model.